# What is the formulae to draw a straight between the given ratio?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graphing-functions

when $X_{min}=50, Y_{min}= 1.0$

when $X_{max} > 50, Y_{max}= 1.5$, 
where $X_{max}$ varies from $51, 52, 53, \ldots$

What is the value of $Y$ at any given point fo $X$? 
If $X_{min}$, $X$ & $X_{max}$ are plotted should produce a straight line.

How to calculate $Y$?

What I tried,

$$Y = \frac{(X)(X_{max} - X_{min})}{(Y_{max} - Y_{min})}$$

Comment: What is the value $X_{max}$ that corresponds to $Y_{max}=1.5$?

Comment: $X_max$ can be any number above 50. Ex. 1700

Comment: If $Y-{max}$ is the same for all values $X>50$ you have **many** stright lines.

Comment: $X_max$ can have only one value at at time, so we shall consider $X_max = 1700$ for $Y_max = 1.5$. What would be the value of `Y` if `50 < X < 1700`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understand you want a stright line that pass thorough the pont $P=(x_m,y_m)=(50,1)$ and a point $P'=(x_M,y_M)=(x_M,1.5)$ with $x_M>50$.

This line has equation:
$$
y-y_m=\dfrac{y_M-y_m}{x_M-x_m}(x-x_m)
$$

So for every value of $x_M$ you have a differnt stringt line:

$$
y-1=\dfrac{1.5-1}{x_M-50}(x-5)
$$